# When dealing with the Law of Demeter, what's an example of a situation where you'd need to change the consumer class, due to over-delegation?

Tags: ruby, law-of-demeter

I often find myself doing lots of [delegating](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate).

In [Ruby Science](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/13-ruby-science), it says:

> Many delegate methods to the same object are an indicator that your
>   object graph may not accurately reflect the real world relationships
>   they represent.

and

> If you find yourself writing lots of delegators, consider changing the
>   consumer class to take a different object. For example, if you need to
>   delegate lots of `User` methods to `Account`, it’s possible that the
>   code referencing `User` should actually reference an instance of
>   `Account` instead.

I don't really understand this. What is an example of how this would look in practice?

Comment: I have a copy of Ruby Science. If you read on a little more into the next paragraphs this should make sense.

Comment: While interesting, the question is ripe for giving opinions, and this probably makes it off topic. I, for one, think the two quotes you mention are utterly wrong without more context: Delegation is an ubiquitous pattern in MVC, and if you need to delegate a lot of User methods to Account, you're doing at least a few things right, aka separation of concerns and (in ruby's own way) dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author of that chapter wants to make clear, that, for example, writing:

```
class User
  def discounted_plan_price(discount_code)
    coupon = Coupon.new(discount_code)
    coupon.discount(account.plan.price)
  end
end
```

Notice `account.plan.price`, could be better done by using `delegate` on the user model, such as:

```
class User
  delegate :discounted_plan_price, to: :account
end
```

which allows you to write the following:

```
class User
  def discounted_plan_price(discount_code)
    account.discounted_plan_price(discount_code)
  end
end

class Account
  def discounted_plan_price(discount_code)
    coupon = Coupon.new(discount_code)
    coupon.discount(plan.price)
  end
end
```

Notice that we write `plan.price`, instead of `account.plan.price`, thanks to the `delegate`.

Good example, but there are many more.

Comment: In other words, this is a case where more delegation is *good*, rather than bad - i.e. the opposite of what OP is requesting. (Not saying you're wrong, btw; on the contrary.)

Comment: I'd be happy to see examples where the Law of Demeter is inherently wrong. :-)